# android adview admob ad back button wont return to original activity

Tags: android, admob, back, adview

I put an admob ad at the bottom on my app's Activity, and when the ad is clicked/pressed it brings up the phone's browser with the ad's url.  When you click the back button from here it returns to the phone's home screen not my app's activity.  I have seen other apps with ads in them that when you click on the ad and then click back it brings you back to the app not the phone's home screen.  I want the back button to bring the user back to my app.  Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with the specific ad creative.  If you try clicking the AdMob test ad (you can specify `adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR)` to get test ads on an emulator), it goes back into the app upon pressing the back button.